# Getting Location in Android

Tags: android, google-play-services, wear-os, android-location, android-context

I am coding on the Android Sample Watch face. I want to connect to Google Play Services to get my current location, and I put this into my OnCreate method:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
    .build();
```

Like so:

[image: The code and where I've placed it along with the errors I received.]

My errors are as following:

The first this cannot be applied to engine. mGoogleApiClient, LocationServices cannot be resolved as a symbol. I've tried implementing/extending my Engine class, and that is not allowed.  The problem might be the class I put this code in since it's probably organized differently? How can I make this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the latest google api update? Are you using Android studio or Eclipse for developing? Are you sure your import are correct and Google Play service is in the same workspace of your project? I had a similar problem and updating with ADT in eclipse fix it.

Comment: I'm on Android Studio and I think Google Play is imported as it's in my manifest and project structure. 6.5.+ is there. The problem might be the class I put this code in since it's probably organized differently? This is inside the AnalogWatchFaceService.